# crontab with php started, but sometimes it doesnt end

Tags: php, linux, cron, command-line-interface

I run a cron job which runs the commandline php
to a script which will call a web service and insert data to the DB for like 7hrs daily.
The weird thing is it sometimes it never ended.

I checked and had already ensure that if exception is caught, it should still continue to the end of the script.  If there's any error in the script, my run.html should show me the error.

my crontab is running a bash script which runs like below every 7 hrs

```
php run.php >> "run.html"
```

The situation now is sometimes, my run.html doesnt has anything written . 0 bytes.

When it is running, it has a pid tied to this process. 
But after 7hrs when nothing is written in run.html, checking the process again (using the command ps -eo pid,lstart,etime,cmd | grep php ), i realise the process already gone.

I do not time is timeout issue as there is no error shown on php_errors.log , and i've already set in my script

```
 ini_set ("memory_limit",0);
```

What other causes could it be?

Comment: Consider writing to run.html when error states occur before the script completes. Maybe there is an error somewhere that causes this to occur. Long-lived processes are usually tricky to debug.

Comment: One thing that might help is adding lots of logging.  Since you're already capturing output, you may want to echo a state occasionally.  You may be hitting bad data that isn't necessarily outputting a php error.

Comment: hmmm, tell me more about it .. the thing is even if i do an echo, the run.html is still blank because it is only rendered after finish compiling the php , followed by my bash script writing to a .html file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on who is hosting your webserver, it's entirely possible that some admin is either rebooting your server or straightforwardly killing your long running process.  (Perhaps he's mistaking it for a zombie?)

I've done a lot of work on sites that are hosted on shared servers, and problems along these lines occur rather frequently, in my experience.  It's sort of a pain, too, given that the problem is non-technical, and all you can really do is move to a different host.

So you might want to look into that.  Send your hosting provider an email and see if they can shed any light on the situation for you.

Good luck.

Comment: not quite true for my case as the server i had is solely used our team and nobody is triggering or killing processes here.